# param is missing or the value is empty: storing entity with relationship in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My application has questions, which have many answers, which have many comments.

However, I am having trouble when trying to save an answer's comment, I am getting this error:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: comment
```

The highlighted line is this one:

```
params.require(:comment).permit(:description)
```

The view where the comment is created is the question's show view, so in the `QuestionController` first I load the `comment`:

```
  def show
    @answer = Answer.new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end
```

And this is how the view looks like:

```
<p>
    <strong>Answers:</strong>
</p>
<% unless @question.answers.empty? %>
    <ul class="list-groups">
    <% @question.answers.each do |answer| %>
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <h4><%= answer.description %></h4>
            <hr>
            <%= form_for(@comment, html: { class: "form-inline" }) do |f| %>

              <div class="form-group">
                <%= text_field_tag 'description', nil, placeholder: 'Comment this answer', class: "form-control" %>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.submit "Comment", class: "btn btn-default" %>
              </div>
              <input id="answer_id" name="answer[id]" type="hidden" value="<%= answer.id %>">
            <% end %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
<% else %>
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'description', nil, placeholder: 'Comment this answer', class: "form-control" %>
```

Use:

```
<%= f.text_field :description, placeholder: 'Comment this answer', class: "form-control" %>
```

You need to use `f`(form_for's object) for binding the attributes of the object(`@comment`) you're trying to build form for, that's why it's not being created properly in HTML and hence not being submitted in comment key inside parameters.